# is there a .NET object which can be json-serialized into a javascript associative array

Tags: asp.net, json.net, associative-array

I have an associative array in javascript:

```
var AA = { 
            'F217': 'fusellage',  
            'P942' : 'propellor'
         }
```

Is there a .NET object which can be json-serialized *directly* into such a representation?  In other words, a server-side object whose json form looks like the javascript object literal above, requiring no further manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I had been trying KeyValuePair but `Dictionary of string, string` works.

Comment: `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` will work also.